# Drive API gives Error 500

Tags: metadata, google-drive-realtime-api

Upon using the [form](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) provided by Google, it fails and gives this response

```
Request


GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0By0Nrrd3XVTUY2pGOTBXTWFWWjQ?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer


Response


500 Internal Server Error

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  66
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 22 Apr 2013 03:08:00 GMT
expires:  Mon, 22 Apr 2013 03:08:00 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Can anyone clarify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Drive API - Error 500 - Simple API Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199088/google-drive-api-error-500-simple-api-access)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it [has been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199088/google-drive-api-error-500-simple-api-access) by Google employee Ali Afshar. (FYI, I think the tag google-drive-sdk is the one that probably got his attention.)

Comment: Thanks Rommel, I noticed it working on my site first, then came here to see what happend